SameSite=None is not set
The firefox tells me that I need to put the value "None" in the somesite attribute, but when I set it, the browser still thinks that Lax is used there, instead of None
enter image description here
(in text:

Some cookies are misusing the recommended "Samesite" attribute 2
Cookie "authToken" does not have a proper "samesite" attribute value.
Soon, cookies without the "SameSite" attribute or with an invalid
value will be treated as "Lax". This means that the cookie will no
longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on
this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the
"SameSite=None" attribute to it. To know more about the "samesite"
attribute, read https://develope
r.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/Samesite
js.cookie.mjs:75:50 Cookie "user" does not have a proper "SameSite”
attribute value. Soon, cookies without the "SameSite" attribute or
with an invalid value will be treated as "Lax". This means that the
cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your
application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts,
please add the "Samesite=None" attribute to it. To know more about the
"samesite" attribute, read https://develope
r.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/Samesite
js.cookie.mjs:75:58

)
Code:
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://59e5-185-9-186-241.ngrok-free.app",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    credentials: true,
  }),
);


app.post("/api/auth/telegram", (req, res) => {
  const userData = req.body;

  // Проверяем подпись
  if (!validateTelegramAuth(userData)) {
    console.log("Неверная подпись Telegram");
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Неверная подпись Telegram" });
  }

  // Генерируем JWT токен
  const token = generateAuthToken(userData);

  res.cookie('authToken', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    partitioned: true,
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});

res.cookie('user', userData, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    partitioned: true,
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});

  
  

  console.log("Токен сгенерирован и отправлен:", token);
  return res.json({ token });
});

I rebooted the server, accessed chatGPT, looked for solutions and similar cases on the Internet

not sure it's relevant, but documentation states the sameSite property can have the following values: boolean true, or strings lax, none or strict - you should try one of those values

please replace the image by the text of the actual error message.

using HTTP or HTTPS? Secure=true and SameSite=none both requires HTTPS

yes, I use https, but I run the server only on local hosting, could it be because of this?
Out of desperation, I tried to put everything that allows me to put somesite, but without success. Moreover, when I look at the cookies myself - there is a SameSite: "None", the browser says the opposite. (well, in general, all cookie settings do not work for me, for example HttpOnly is written false in the browser, although I set true - similarly with secure, although what is on the server that I have https on the client)
